# How do i add class="fancybox" to the default gallery?

Tags: gallery

i tried this shortcode:

> [gallery class="fancybox" link="file" columns="5"]

But the class="fancybox" isn't been added to the a href tag of each image.

How can i add class="fancybox" to each a href tag??

ps: where is the source code of gallery?

Comment: ok  i am testing with add_filter('wp_get_attachment_link' but how do i make sure it only applies to the shortcode Gallery?

Comment: Ok i added this but i like to make sure it only applies to the gallery shortcode, how do i do this?
`function my_get_attachment_link($html) {
    $postid = get_the_ID();
    $html = str_replace('<a', '<a class="fancybox"', $html);
    return $html;
}

add_filter('wp_get_attachment_link', 'my_get_attachment_link', 10, 1);`

Comment: Why not change the javascript selector that fancybox works on?

Comment: @sanchothefat is on the right track. You're looking at the problem wrong. You're increasing the overhead of processing the gallery for no good reason.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use javascript/jquery to solve this.

When you insert a gallery in a wordpress posts, the whole gallery is wrapped by a div with id like "gallery-1" but also a class that's always "gallery".
Also, every item is surrounded by two other "dl" and "dt", with class "gallery-item" and "gallery-icon" respectively.

So, you can just use jquery to match every link inside those classes, and add whatever lightbox script you want.

If it's fancybox, i think something like this should work:

```
jQuery(".gallery-icon a").fancybox();
```

You can be more specific, matching css classes **.gallery .gallery-item .gallery-icon** in that order and then the **a** (for the link).

For the new Gutenberg galleries, this should work:

```
jQuery(".wp-block-gallery .blocks-gallery-item a").fancybox();
```

If you want users can navigate between images as a gallery, then use:

```
jQuery(".gallery-icon a").fancybox().attr('data-fancybox', 'gallery');
```

And for the new Gutenberg galleries, use this instead:

```
jQuery(".wp-block-gallery .blocks-gallery-item a").fancybox().attr('data-fancybox', 'gallery');
```

If you want more grained control (for multiple galleries on the same page), [check this response](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/181728/13975).

Or use a simple plugin that use the same approach [from Viper007Bond](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jquery-lightbox-for-native-galleries/), that does clean and nicely, but using colorbox instead.

Comment: jQuery runs in no-conflict mode in WordPress. I changed your code accordingly. Oh, and welcome to WordPress Stack Exchange!

Comment: Just make sure that the gallery is set to link to the file, not the attachment page. Caught me out!

Answer (score 6):

```
jQuery(".gallery-icon a").fancybox().attr('data-fancybox', 'wp-gallery-fancybox');
```

Gives all links the same rel attribute, this way the user will be able to slide between the images.

Answer (score 2):

These answer were all right but now fancybox has changed it's spec. It's no longer rel=gallery, but "data-fancybox=gallery". So the new scripts should look like this

```
 jQuery(".gallery-icon a").fancybox().attr('data-fancybox', 'gallery');
```

and

```
jQuery('.gallery').each(function() {
            // set the rel for each gallery
            jQuery(this).find(".gallery-icon a").attr('data-fancybox', 'group-' + jQuery(this).attr('id'));
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

to build on @kaiser here -

Each gallery ideally would get a unique id, but now that posts and pages can have multiple galleries, its not easy with php to give each gallery a unique rel identifier.

```
jQuery('.gallery').each(function (g) {
    jQuery('a', this).attr('rel', function (i, attr) {
         return attr + ' gallery-' + g;
    });
});`
```

Mind your selectors, your theme might rewrite them. This is discussed in depth on http://kaspars.net/blog/wordpress/add-rel-attribute-to-each-gallery-post